# Method of one class as callback from another

Tags: c++, avr

I will describe my problem the simplest as I can.

**What is my issue:**

I have frist class as a singleton:

```
class CTimer1
{
public:
    static CTimer1 * getInstance();       //This gives me pointer to instance
    void setChannelA(uint8_t compareValue);
private:
    //Cnstructors
    CTimer1();  //Prevent consttuction but allow in getInstance
    CTimer1(const CTimer1&);    //Prevent construction by copying
    CTimer1& operator=(const CTimer1&); //Prevent assigment
    ~CTimer1();                 //Prevent unwanted destruction
    static CTimer1 * timerInstance;
    static bool isCreated;
};
```

And here is second class where I would like to have possibility to call `setChannelA` method from `CTimer1` class as a `setPwm` method from `CServo` class:

```
class CServo {
public:
    CServo();
    ~CServo();

public:
    //public methods
    void registerPwmTimer(void (*callback)(uint8_t u8_buffer));

    void (*setPwm)(uint8_t u8_buffer);   //As this method I would like to call setChannelA from CTimer1 class
};
```

Here is `registerPwmTimer` method:

```
void CServo::registerPwmTimer(void (*callback)(uint8_t u8_buffer))
{
    setPwm = callback;
}
```

Then I have tried to assign pointer to this method as a following:

```
int main()
{   
    CTimer1 * timer1 = CTimer1::getInstance();
    CServo servo1();
    servo1.registerPwmTimer(timer1->setChannelA);
    servo1.setPwm(10);       //This is example how I want to call setChannelA method

    while(1)
    {

    }
}
```

I have error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'CServo::registerPwmTimer(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

**What is important:**

I can't use `std::function` because this is some part of code in C++ for embedded device, so I need to save memory consumption. Is there any way that I will be able to achieve this effect? If ony one possibility to do this is ot use some std library please for answers too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to make `void setChannelA(uint8_t compareValue)` function static or change `void registerPwmTimer(void (*callback)(uint8_t u8_buffer))` to `void registerPwmTimer(void (*CTimer1::mem_fun_callback)(uint8_t u8_buffer), CTimer& obj)` because of non-static member function have no sense without corresponding object since member functions use `this` pointer inside.

Comment: void registerPwmTimer(void (CTimer1::*mem_fun_callback)(uint8_t u8_buffer), CTimer& obj) is the correct member function pointer declaration

Comment: You could also use `std::function<void(uint8_t)>` instead of a function pointer type. Then the caller can use lambda syntax or `std::bind(&CTimer1::setChannelA, timer1)` to bind a reference to the `timer1` object to the callback. (But note that if the callback is invoked after `timer1` gets destructed, the result is undefined behavior.)

Comment: @em2er as long as the callback is a *C++ function* (no "extern C" declaration), there's no need to use a static member function.

Comment: try `servo1.registerPwmTimer(&Ctimer1::setChannelA);`

Comment: I have tried @em2er solution, but I still get error: `expected id-expression before '*' `

Comment: @tofro You need both a member function pointer *and* an object on which to invoke that member function. This is what `std::bind` allows you to encapsulate into a single `std::function` object.

Comment: @agreed you need to have an object to call a method on - But the member function pointer doesn't need to be to a `static` member function as long as you have an instance-

Comment: @tofro Right -- but in your example (`servo1.registerPwmTimer(&Ctimer1::setChannelA);`) you do not provide any instance.

Comment: @cdhowie Yep - Because that's the minimum that needs to be done to get rid of the compilation error. Agree that on an AVR, I'd probably use a static member function. But the statement "needs to be static" is wrong.

Comment: @tofro It won't though, unless that method is made static. Pointer-to-function and pointer-to-member-function are totally different types. You'll just get a different compilation error stating that `void (CTimer::*)(uint8_t)` can't be converted to `void (*)(uint8_t)`.

Comment: @tofro I never said it needed to be static. Indeed, my answer shows one way you can accomplish this without the member function being static. I was just pointing out that your fix *("try `servo1.registerPwmTimer(&Ctimer1::setChannelA);`")* doesn't actually fix anything. It just trades one compiler error for another.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with passing member function and object's pointer in this way: `void CServo::registerPwmTimer(void (*callback)(uint8_t u8_buffer), CTimer1 * pTimer)`, but how can I assign this callback to `setPwm` member pointer? I have tried this `setPwm = pTimer->*callback`, but it's not working ?

Comment: @drewpol **Pointer-to-function and pointer-to-member-function are different and wholly incompatible types.** The type you are looking for is `void (CTimer::*callback)(uint8_t)`, but note that this couples the `CServo` class to `CTimer`, making `CTimer` member functions the *only* acceptable callback. See the second part of my answer. Is there a reason you do not want to use `std::function`?

Comment: @cdhowie Ok, so when I declare this as `void registerPwmTimer(void (CTimer1::*callback)(uint8_t u8_buffer), CTimer1 * pTimer)` there isn't any way to assign this callback to member method of `CServo` class in this way as I have tried before? I don't exacly know how to implement Your solution in second part. I mean polymorphic wrapper. Can You give me some examples or tips?

Comment: The simple answer is that `std::function` is exactly the polymorphic wrapper you want, and (the best part) *it already exists!*

Comment: @drewpol I have updated my answer to provide an example of a *very* basic polymorphic callable wrapper. Hopefully this convinces you that `std::function` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that a function pointer necessarily has to point to a static function.  When you invoke an instance function (a method) there is a hidden first argument, which is the object on which the function was invoked.  (This hidden argument is available as `this` within the function's definition.)

Your `CServo::registerPwmTimer()` function signature is simply incompatible with invocation of a member function; function pointers alone do not provide a way to bind an argument to the pointer, so even if you could convey the member function pointer using a (free) function pointer type, the hidden `this` argument could not be determined when the function pointer was invoked.

To put it another way, it would fail for the same reason that trying `CTimer1::setChannelA(0)` would fail -- you want to invoke that method, but you haven't communicated which object on which to invoke it.

Change the signature of `CServo::registerPwmTimer` to accept an [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object instead of a raw function pointer. `std::function` objects can be constructed from function pointers, but they can also be constructed from lambdas, and some standard library functions return function objects:

```
void registerPwmTimer(std::function<void(uint8_t)>);
```

Now, you can use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to create a new function that binds the object instance to the member function pointer:

```
servo1.registerPwmTimer(std::bind(&CTimer1::setChannelA, timer1));
```

Note that `std::bind` *does not* extend the lifetime of the object pointed to by `timer1`.  If the returned function is invoked after that object is destructed, the result is undefined behavior.

---

Another alternative would be to accept both an instance and a pointer to a member function.  The problem with this approach is it requires using templates:

```
template <typename T>
void registerPwmTimer(void (T::*)(uint8_t), T&);
```

This isn't bad in itself, but what you'll wind up doing is creating a polymorphic wrapper class so that you can insert this into your callback list alongside other callbacks that don't share the same `T`.  At that point, *you're just recreating `std::function`*, since `std::function` already serves the purpose of being a polymorphic wrapper around callable things.

---

To illustrate the mess of implementing a polymorphic callable wrapper yourself, here is a very light example.  I will show the declarations of a set of these types, and link to an example implementation.

This is the base type, with a pure virtual `operator()` that serves as the invocation operation.

```
class poly_callable
{
public:
    virtual void operator()(int) const = 0;
};
```

Now we have a type for function pointers (also works with pointer-to-functor):

```
template <typename T>
class fn_poly_callable : public poly_callable
{
public:
    typedef T fn_type;

    fn_poly_callable(T);
    virtual void operator()(int) const;

private:
    T fn;
};
```

And one for member functions -- oh, but `const` member functions and non-`const` member functions are not interchangeable, so we need an extra template parameter for that:

```
template <typename T, typename M = void (T::*)(int)>
class member_poly_callable : public poly_callable
{
public:
    typedef T object_type;
    typedef M member_fn_type;

    member_poly_callable(member_fn_type, object_type&);
    virtual void operator()(int) const;

private:
    member_fn_type mfn;
    object_type& target;
};
```

Plus we'll want some helper functions to allow the compiler to infer the template types.  One for function pointers:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<poly_callable> make_poly_callable(T fn)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<poly_callable>(new fn_poly_callable<T>(fn));
}
```

Two for member functions (`const` and non-`const`):

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<poly_callable> make_poly_callable(void (T::*mfn)(int), T& target)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<poly_callable>(new member_poly_callable<T>(mfn, target));
}

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<poly_callable> make_poly_callable(void (T::*mfn)(int) const, T& target)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<poly_callable>(new member_poly_callable<T, void (T::*)(int) const>(mfn, target));
}
```

If you want to see it all in action, I made a ["simple" and working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b860f06e14842d5e).

So... just use `std::function`.  There's *no reason* to reinvent this stuff.

Comment: You're awesome ! Now I have starded to understand what going on with this. Have a nice day ! That is this what I really need .